# SVG translate to bottom edge in pixel units

Tags: svg

The goal is to make an SVG shape that vertically sizes with its container, but has pixel perfect polygons at the top and bottom edge. Something that looks like this:

[image]

The top and bottom triangles should remain the same size (8 pixels high) no matter how vertically large the container gets. Conceptually what I want is a solid rectangle 100% high, and small white triangles to cut out the 4 corners. Ideally it would be like:

```
    <div style="position:relative;padding-left:20px;width:200px;border:1px solid black;">
            <svg  style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:16px;">
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="16" height="100%" style="fill:green"/>
                <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,8"   style="fill:white"/>
                <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,8" style="fill:white"/> 
                <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,-8"   style="fill:white" transform="translate(0, 100%)"/>
                <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,-8" style="fill:white" transform="translate(0, 100%)"/> 
            </svg>
            This is the<br>div content<br>of some random<br>vertical size.
    </div>
```

But of course that does not work because you cannot use percentage values in the translate(). The obvious solution is a viewBox which is 100 units high:

```
<div style="position:relative;padding-left:20px;width:200px;border:1px solid black;">
        <svg  style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:16px;" viewBox="0 0 16 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="16" height="100%" style="fill:green"/>
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,8"   style="fill:white"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,8" style="fill:white"/> 
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,-8"   style="fill:white" transform="translate(0, 100)"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,-8" style="fill:white" transform="translate(0, 100)"/> 
        </svg>
        This is the<br>div content<br>of some random<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>vertical size.
</div>
```

The result is functional, but now all the polygon points are scaled vertically causing the triangles at the top and bottom to stretch when the container gets larger:

[image]

How to get the top/bottom triangle polygons to remain (exactly) 8 pixels high, while allowing the overall size to stretch vertically? If there were a way to translate to the bottom edge without a viewBox (staying the the browser's pixel units) then the first code snippet would work.

Comment: you'd need to recalculate the polygon everytime the container stretches using javascript

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1. Nested `<svg>`s

It it possible to have an `<svg>` element inside another `<svg>` element, so you can put the bottom two rectangles in their own `<svg>` with their own `viewBox` like this:

```
            <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet" viewBox="0 -0.1 16 0.1">
                    <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,-8"   style="fill:white"/>
                    <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,-8" style="fill:white"/> 
            </svg>
```

The viewBox containing the bottom triangles will be placed at the center of the bottom side of the viewport (`xMidYMax`) and the will be scaled as much as possible to fit into the viewport (`meet`). Since the viewBox is only 0.1 units high, it can hardly excede the height of the viewport being scaled, so it will be bounded by its width. More on `preserveAspectRatio` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio).

#### Method 2. CSS Transforms

Unlike svg transformations, CSS transforms allow for percentages, so you can instead of `transform="translate(0, 100)"` you can use `style="transform:translateY(100%);"` For this to work, however, you need to give your `<svg>` an appropriate viewBox, again with very low height. This is because if the viewBox is higher than the container, the triangles end up at the bootom of the viewBox, below the bottom of the container.

See examples in the code snippet:

```html
<style>
div {position:relative;padding-left:20px;width:130px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;resize:vertical;overflow:auto;float:left;}
svg {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:16px;}
</style>
These 4 methods all work as static but only the left 2 work if the height changes.<br>
The &lt;div&gt;s are resizable, so you can see for yourself. 
<br>
<div>
        <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="16" height="100%" style="fill:green"/>
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,8"   style="fill:white"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,8" style="fill:white"/>
        <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet" viewBox="0 -0.1 16 0.1">
                <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,-8"   style="fill:white"/>
                <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,-8" style="fill:white"/> 
        </svg>
        </svg>
        <span style="color:green">nested &lt;svg&gt;s</span>
</div>

<div>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 16 0.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="16" height="100%" style="fill:green"/>
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,8"   style="fill:white"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,8" style="fill:white"/> 
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,-8"   style="fill:white;transform:translateY(100%);"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,-8" style="fill:white;transform:translateY(100%);"/> 
        </svg>
    <span style="color:green">CSS transforms,<br>viewBox height 0.1</span>
</div>

<div>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 16 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="16" height="100%" style="fill:green"/>
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,8"   style="fill:white"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,8" style="fill:white"/> 
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,-8"   style="fill:white;transform:translateY(100%);"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,-8" style="fill:white;transform:translateY(100%);"/> 
        </svg>
    <span style="color:red">CSS transforms,<br>viewBox height 100</span>
</div>

<div>
        <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="16" height="100%" style="fill:green"/>
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,8"   style="fill:white"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,8" style="fill:white"/> 
            <polygon points="0,0 8,0 0,-8"   style="fill:white;transform:translateY(100%);"/>
            <polygon points="8,0 16,0 16,-8" style="fill:white;transform:translateY(100%);"/> 
        </svg>
    <span style="color:red">CSS transforms<br>without viewBox</span><br>Chrome and Firefox<br>behave differently!
</div>
```